# Rendering items in PHP nested loop

Tags: php, sql, loops

I am rendering a page in PHP showing several items, each of them having a number of images.
The problem here is getting the script to render exact number of images for each item.

I have used nested loops, but that doesn't seem do work properly for me.
Here it goes:

```
<?php 
for ($k = 0; $k < $itemsnumber; $k++){ 
    $itemresresult = mysqli_query($dbconn, "SELECT * FROM 
                                            `item_resource` 
                                            WHERE i_itemnumber = ".$k.";");                                                                
    while($res = $itemresresult->fetch_assoc()){
     ...render images
    }
}
?>
```

I want it to render only images associated with the k increment of the first loop, however, it would render all the images with i_itemnumber = 1,2 etc..

Comment: What isn't working? Can you be more specific?

Comment: Hi, not sure I understand what your problem is. I dont think you have shown us enough code to be able to understand what you are actually trying to do

Comment: "I want it to render only images associated with the k increment of the first loop". This isn't entirely making sense to me. Let's say $itemsnumber = 3. Therefore $k will be 0 the first time the loop runs, then 1 next time, etc. So the loop will run 4 times. Therefore your SELECT will run 4 times. Each time you'll run a different query with a different value of $k. So eventually it will output all rows where the i_itemnumber is between 0 and 3.

Comment: you are iterating k over <0,$itemsnumber), so your $k will be 0, 1, 2... etc.

Comment: You don't need a loop for that though, you could just write `SELECT * FROM 
                                            item_resource 
                                            WHERE i_itemnumber >= 0 and i_item_number <= 3`. Or even `SELECT * FROM 
                                            item_resource 
                                            WHERE i_itemnumber IN (0,1,2,3)` if you prefer. You can construct that query easily from your code since you know 0 is the starting point and 3 is the end point (due to the value of $itemsnumber). Much more efficient to do it in one query.

Comment: If you're saying that you only want to execute it for a specific value, then don't use the for loop...just choose a specific number and query it directly. Maybe you just need `SELECT * FROM 
                                            item_resource 
                                            WHERE i_itemnumber = ".$itemsnumber.";"` or something. I don't know, that's just a guess. The way you've worded the question doesn't make it fully clear what you are trying to do. It would help to give us a proper example of the table data and the expected output of your code. We are not mind-readers.

Comment: SHow us more code from BEFORE this section of code, I am sure that will make it more obvious to us what you are asking here

Comment: Database queries inside loops are generally considered bad practice, not good for performance. This should probably rather be one query reading all the data you need, properly sorted - and then you implement a _control break_ to output them grouped by item.

Comment: `<?php for ($k = 0; $k < $itemsnumber; $k++){ ?>  
 <div class="col-wrp">                 
            <div class="col-main">                
                <div class = "wrapper-images">                                                
   <div class="slider">                                                     
                      <?php while($res = $itemresresult->fetch_assoc()){                
                                   <div class="slider-item" class="photos">...image</div>
                                 } ?> </div></div></div></div>`

Comment: I actually think foreach should be used, as @Volvox said below

Comment: @BogdanNechaenko what makes you think that? Can you explain your reason? See my comment under Volvox's answer...there's a very obvious way to make that code more efficient. But again as we said earlier, you really need to make it clear to us what the input data looks like, and what you actually want the final output to be.

Comment: @BogdanNechaenko in future please don't add code into the comments. It belongs in the question itself, so please edit the question instead. That way, it's shown in context, it's obvious for people reading the question, and it can be formatted in a much more readable way. Thanks.

Comment: @ADyson Ok sir, i will do my best in the future. Not being a really experienced user of this website, so you should pardon my wrong formatting in this one

Comment: @BogdanNechaenko no that's fine, I understand. We all have to learn sometime...that's why I was pointing it out for the future.

Comment: @BogdanNechaenko anyway, it's more important to clarify your question in the way I suggested, in terms of making clear what you are actually trying to output from your code.

Comment: @ADyson yep, I understand, and I think Volvox has got it right in his layout, you just have say a list item and several images appended to that with i_itemnumber corresponding to each item. As simple as that

Comment: ok. But you don't need to run 3 queries for that, you can run one query. If the results are ordered by item number, you can generate a new list item every time you notice that the item number is different from the previous row's item number. It's always more efficient to use as few SQL queries as possible.

Comment: @ADyson you're right, that works just the same way

Comment: @ADyson I mean, this way we still have to execute the query inside the foreach loop to access each item, providing that `$items` has got a variable number of items, so to my mind not a big change from Volvox's post..

Comment: "I mean, this way we still have to execute the query inside the foreach loop to access each item". No, you don't. You execute the query once, selecting _all_ items that you know you want (because you already know the item numbers up-front, since they are loaded into $items). From the $items array you can build the `IN` clause of a single query and run that, once, to get everything you need.

Comment: Then you get all the results in one bigger result set. Then you loop through those results. As I mentioned, if you put them in to the right order then you can just create a new `<li>` every time you detect that the current row's item number ID is different from the ID on the previous row (a simple variable can be used to keep track)

Comment: "From the $items array you can build the IN clause of a single query and run that, once". Pray show me the code how it is done. As long as it's not a big trouble of course

Comment: with a simple loop through the $items array and some string concatenation. Take a look at this runnable demo:  http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/01dd917d906bf564d38afb9c069b4da0eb19f334

Comment: @ADyson I got your point, this time you implement foreach, but instead of querying you use it to create a string. Good idea +

Answer (score -1):

You should do something like this:

```php
$items = [
    ["id"=>1, 'name' => "first item"],
    ["id"=>2, 'name' => "second item"],
    ["id"=>3, 'name' => "third item"]
];

    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ($items as $item){
       echo '<li>' . $item['name'];
       $itemresresult = mysqli_query($dbconn, "SELECT * FROM 
                                            `item_resource` 
                                            WHERE i_itemnumber = ".$item['id'].";");
       while($res = $itemresresult->fetch_assoc()){
           ...render images
       }
       echo '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
```

As you see you need to render images in loop with corresponding image. Also not that i used ID from `$item` in SQL query, not iteration number.

Comment: A single query `SELECT * FROM 
                                            item_resource 
                                            WHERE i_itemnumber IN (1, 2, 3)` would be a much more efficient way to do it. Executing multiple SQL queries where a single one could be used is just a waste of CPU and bandwidth.

Comment: @ADyson "Premature optimization is the root of all evil". While your comment is correct, it would lead to more complicated answer. With such a trivial problem, performance probably will not be any issue.

Comment: Hmm, that's assuming that it's always going to be a small number of items. If you start to get a much longer list, then it'll get a lot less efficient to make that number of queries. Some slightly more complex PHP will be a reasonable tradeoff compared to having to run _n_ number of SQL queries. That's just my opinion, of course, but in general that's been my experience of actual usage too